# I'm not able to build my unity project into apk

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm not able to build my unity project into apk, whenever i try to build it throw errors

**I'm using unity 2020.3.21**

I'm using api level 31 because i want to submit the update of my game on playstore and now they changed the api level to 31.

**errors**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 33.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with -
```

**The other error**

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 33.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
```

As i can see in the error it is mentioned that **Build Tools revision 33.0.0 is corrupted**  i already renistalled using the android studio but still the same error or maybe i did it wrong. if you know anything about this error then you are welcome any help should be appericiated.

Answer (score 0):

try to install via unity package manager instead of android studio since it may have different file names for the different applications

hope this helps!

Comment: **Build Tools revision 33.0.0** is not avialable in unity package manager it can be only installed using the android studio sdk manager. if it installable using the package manager then tell me procedure on how can i do that